# Finite range of a map $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: slope

Let $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a map with the property:
$E^{+}_{\rho} = \{\rho(m + n) - \rho(m) - \rho(n) \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
is a finite set and $\rho(-n) = -\rho(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We call such maps are *odd slopes*.

- ***My promplem:***

If $\rho$ is an odd slope and there is an infinite set $X \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $\rho(X)$ is a finite set, then $\rho(\mathbb{N})$ is a finite set.

- ***My attempt:***

From $\rho(X)$ is finite, $\{\rho(m + n) \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m,n \in X\}$ is finite by $E^{+}_{\rho}$. $A = \{k_m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite where

$k_m := \min \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists n \in X: m + k = n\}$

$A$ is finite then $\rho(A)$ is finite therefore, for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, exists $k_m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that: exists $u \in E^{+}_{\rho}$, $v \in \rho(X)$ and $w \in \rho(A)$:

$\rho(m) = \rho(m + k_m) - \rho(k_m) - u = \rho(n) - \rho(k_m) - u = v - w - u$

takes its values in a finite set. Hence, the set $\{\rho(m) \in \mathbb{Z} \mid m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite $\Leftrightarrow \rho(\mathbb{N})$ is finite.

- ***My question:***

I can not prove $A$ is finite. Maybe my approach or my problem statement was wrong. I hope your help.